# Are onmousedown and onmouseup supported on touch screen devices?

Tags: html, mobile, touch

I just wanted to ask if onmouseup and onmousedown events are supported on touch screen mobile devices when deployed.

I have this code here:

```
<img src="images/plus.png" id="+" onclick=compare(this.id) onmousedown=changeplus() onmouseup=changeplus2() class=plus_button style="width:100px; height:100px;">
```

And I'm not sure if the device will support those.

I can't test it because I don't have the device yet.
If it is not, is there any alternative for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use obtrusive event handlers!

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate Touch events, in Chrome browser easily.

1- Press F12 to see Developer Tools
2- Click on the 'Settings' icon in bottom-right corner
3- Go to 'Override' section in Settings Panel
4- Activate check-box: 'Emulate Touch Events'

That's all! Ready to test your code.